# What is the basis of this vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be set of $2\times2$ matrices $A$ with complex enteties and wich satisfy $a_{11}+a_{22}=0$. I have varified that $V$ is a vector space over both the field of reals and complex numbers. But I want  to know what is the basis of this when the field is reals and when the field is complex  numbers.
Also the set $W$ of all skew Harmitian matrices will be a subspace of it, what is basis of $W$.

Comment: Do you mean $a_{11} + a_{22} = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $V$ is isomorphic to $U = \{\mathbf x \in \mathbb{F}^4\mid x_0 + x_1 = 0 \}$, where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Also,
$$ \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_0\\x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_0\\-x_0\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then you can find a basis for $U$ and map this basis back to $V$ using a bijective linear map.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_{11} + a_{22} = 0$, then $a_{22} = -a_{11}$ and so a general matrix in your space will be

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & -a_{11} \end{array}\right) = a_{11}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right) + a_{12}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right) + a_{21}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right).$$

Can you take it from here?